# Select rows using in with comma-separated string parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm converting a stored procedure from MySql to SQL Server. The procedure has one input parameter `nvarchar`/`varchar` which is a comma-separated string, e.g.

```
'1,2,5,456,454,343,3464'
```

I need to write a query that will retrieve the relevant rows, in MySql I'm using `FIND_IN_SET` and I wonder what the equivalent is in SQL Server.

I also need to order the ids as in the string.

The original query is:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM table_name t
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,p_ids)
 ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id,p_ids);
```

Comment: You need to either parse your string into the values, use dynamic sql, or change your list into a table parameter. I would avoid the dynamic sql for this unless you absolutely must, a table parameter is probably the best choice performance wise followed by splitting the string.

Comment: Tx, I will read about table parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent is `like` for the `where` and then `charindex()` for the `order by`:

```
select *
from table_name t
where ','+p_ids+',' like '%,'+cast(id as varchar(255))+',%'
order by charindex(',' + cast(id as varchar(255)) + ',', ',' + p_ids + ',');
```

Well, you could use `charindex()` for both, but the `like` will work in most databases.

Note that I've added delimiters to the beginning and end of the string, so 464 will not accidentally match 3464.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write a FIND_IN_SET function as it does not exist. The closet mechanism I can think of to convert a delimited string into a joinable object would be a to create a [table-valued function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=SQL.105).aspx) and use the result in a standard in statement.  It would need to be similar to:

```
DECLARE @MyParam NVARCHAR(3000)

SET @MyParam='1,2,5,456,454,343,3464'

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    MyTable 
WHERE 
    MyTableID IN (SELECT ID FROM dbo.MySplitDelimitedString(@MyParam,','))
```

And you would need to create a `MySplitDelimitedString` type [table-valued function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=SQL.105).aspx) that would split a string and return a `TABLE (ID INT)` object.

Answer (score 0):

A set based solution that splits the id's into ints and join with the base table which will make use of index on the base table id. I assumed the id would be an int, otherwise just remove the cast.

```
declare @ids nvarchar(100) = N'1,2,5,456,454,343,3464';

with nums as ( -- Generate numbers
    select top (len(@ids)) row_number() over (order by (select 0)) n
    from sys.messages
)
, pos1 as ( -- Get comma positions
    select c.ci
    from nums n
        cross apply (select charindex(',', @ids, n.n) as ci) c
    group by c.ci
)
, pos2 as ( -- Distinct posistions plus start and end
    select ci
    from pos1
    union select 0
    union select len(@ids) + 1
)
, pos3 as ( -- add row number for join
    select ci, row_number() over (order by ci) as r
    from pos2
)
, ids as ( -- id's and row id for ordering
    select cast(substring(@ids, p1.ci + 1, p2.ci - p1.ci - 1) as int) id, row_number() over (order by p1.ci) r
    from pos3 p1
        inner join pos3 p2 on p2.r = p1.r + 1
)
select *
from ids i
    inner join table_name t on t.id = i.id
order by i.r;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this by using regex to get the input values from comma separated string :

`select * from table_name where id in (
   select regexp_substr(p_ids,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
   connect by regexp_substr(p_ids, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null );`